# Python win32 - Why is my .Restrict by date failing when pulling Outlook calendar data?

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I am using win32 to pull Outlook calendar data and I cannot seem to specify a start date, so it is pulling all of my data for the last ~5 years. In the example below, I'd like to pull events only if they are after 11/1/2020. It doesn't throw an error when I put it into a dataframe. It just simply doesn't work and continues to include everything.

I could just filter the dates after they are in the dataframe, however, its making the run time of the script quite long.

```
import win32com.client
import calendar

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace('MAPI')
calendar = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(9)
appointments = calendar.Items
appointments.sort('[Start]')
appointments.IncludeRecurrences = True
appointments.restrict("[Start] > '11/1/2020 12:00 AM'")
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm running into exactly the same problem.